# Downgrade Xcode SDK for app submission

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I submitted an update to the AppStore last week with the latest SDK - Xcode 5.1.
However, I'm facing unexpected UI issues on iPhone 5S which I didn't previously find while testing on the iOS 64-bit simulator.

This seems clearly to be an SDK issue. 
I'm thinking the quickest solution now would be to submit another update with the older Xcode version 5.0.2.

Is this a good idea?
Please suggest some pros & cons.

Comment: Your options will be to: 1. Just open your project in Xcode 5.0.2 and rebuild from there. 2. If it really is a 64bit issue, remove 64bit archs from your build settings and 3. Do the right thing and figure out what the issue is and fix it. The symptoms that are manifesting may point to a deeper issue that might still be there even if you avoid the symptoms. Are you sure it's a 64 bit issue or could it be something else? Have you tried the 64bit iPad simulator or device? Could it be the screen size? Do you get the same bugs on an iPhone 5?

Comment: I'm certain it's not screen size, and it's an iPhone-only app. The bug does not occur on any device except iPhone 5S. The 64-bit architecture is the only difference between iPhone 5S and iPhone 5C/iPhone 5. What I'm concerned about is I'm unable to replicate the bug in the 64-bit simulator. Could this be due to a build setting in debug mode? Could you please elaborate a little more on point 2?

Comment: Unless this is an outright (and obvious) Apple bug you really need to fix this in your app as at some point Apple will require 64-bit slices.  What is the exact UI issue you are having in your 64-bit build with Xcode 5.1?

Comment: @RoboticCat,

One particular button whose y-value is calculated from `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` is misplaced in iPhone 5S but rendered correctly on all other devices/iOS versions.

Comment: That's odd. What are you using - Frames and direct positioning or Auto-layout? Or are you using Struts/Springs? Have you debugged (on a device) any positioning / constraints code you have written to make sure this is not a logic problem? It would seem to me that if a wrong `[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` value is being returned it should be very easy to prove that it's not your code.

Comment: This particular view uses frames & direct positioning.
Even I'm skeptical that `[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` could return a wrong value.
The main problem is - there's overwhelming evidence from customer feedback and analytics that the problem is restricted to iPhone 5S, but it doesn't occur in the 64-bit simulator.
That's why it's a little scary what else could be wrong in the 64-bit architecture (which I haven't tested on a test device - only on simulator), and it seems a safer option in the short term to simply revert to Xcode 5.0.2.

Comment: Hmmm...you need to debug on the actual device to be sure. Also, I have to think this is a problem in your code. `1.`Can you update your question to post the code where you position or re-position the button? `2.`And (if possible) include a screenshot from a customer along with a screenshot of a correct screen. There are some great coders on SO who may spot something in your code.

Comment: Since this is production code, I won't be allowed to post code snippets or actual screenshots.
However I will stay on this for the next couple of days and post my findings. Debugging on an actual device will definitely clarify things a whole lot.
Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: @RoboticCat,
I found the cause of my issue to be exactly as described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691264/uibutton-doesnt-appear-on-iphone-5s

When I remove the `weak` reference from my UIButton, it started working normally again.

Comment: Glad to hear that you tracked the issue down! A few general comments though: Even though it's an iPhone-only app, it *will* still run on an iPad, but in a letter boxed mode resembling the iPhone 4 resolution. I'd be particularly curious what it does on an iPad Air, which has the same chip as the iPhone 5S. I'd also be curious curious, is the device running the same iOS version as the simulator? XC 5.1 has iOS 7.1 (and does support a few older versions). Robotic Cat is right, Apple will eventually require 64bit support, my guess is before the end of the year.

Comment: @BergQuester,

From my tests and analytics data, I found that the issue existed on iPhone 5S as well as iPad Air devices running previous iOS versions (but only for the App version built from Xcode 5.1) as well as iOS 7.1.
Agree with you (and RoboticCat) on the 64-bit slices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was because of the UIButton defined `weak`, which failed to get allocated on 64-bit devices for the app update submitted from Xcode 5.1
Interestingly, UIViews and UILabels declared in a similar way did NOT fail to get memory allocations.

Looking back at my original question, it was probably best to fix the issues under the latest SDK rather than reverting to an older version.